# Getting reliable MSISDN from Android Phone? VoiceMailNumber Line1Number

Tags: java, android, phone-number, telephonymanager, msisdn

First off the [MSISDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSISDN) is the same as the phone number. 
I have been looking into seeing if it if possible to get the phone number off of an Andoid phone.

The result of my research was yes and no.

It is possible using [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and [getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29).  However this is unreliable.

I have tested the above with a Motorola Atrix and this does not retrieve a valid phone number. So dead in the water right?

Well I was able to get the phone number off the phone using [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and [getVoiceMailNumber()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getVoiceMailNumber%28%29).

I would not have ever guessed that the voicemail number would be my actual phone's number (MSISDN).

So my question is that would checking either [getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) or [getVoiceMailNumber()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getVoiceMailNumber%28%29) be a reliable way to get MSISDN? (ie: if getLine1Number returns 0000000000000, then check getVoiceMailNumber or something along those lines.)

No one on this website has mentioned before being able to get MSISDN from [getVoiceMailNumber()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getVoiceMailNumber%28%29) and this is definitely not apparent and almost contradictory to the documentation, but the fact is that it works for my particular device.  (untested on other devices)

Comment: How can this question be flagged as a duplicate when it was asked almost a year before the other question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It wont be 100% reliable if you use getVoiceMailNumber(). A lot of times this may give the phone number but what if the handset gets a firmware update and this number changes to something else? say a short code? So no, it is not reliable.

If you can get the number from getLine1Number() then why dont you prompt user to enter the number? You can verify it by sending that number an SMS message with a short code, which the user will be required to enter in the app before proceeding further.

Comment: Thanks omermuhammed, that is a creative solution. It's too bad that it isn't 100% reliable. I am thinking that IMSI might be a better approach for what I need than MSISDN. Seams to be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question. However, I would like to share some information which may help people in the future:

> `getLine1Number()` Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.

MSISDN is the phone number. However, MSISDN is stored in a file in the SIMCard. Main problem is that it is not mandatory to fill that file. So, you have some simcards which includes MSISDN while other simcards does not have that information.

So, read the MSISDN is totally NOT reliable.

> `getVoiceMailNumber()` Returns the voice mail number. Return null if it is unavailable.

This is also not reliable since this number changes from carrier to carrier. Some carrier uses as voice mail your own phone number. However, some other carriers uses a different number like *55 or something like that.

So, it is very difficult to determine your own phone number. So, avoid to use phone number.

Comment: "However, MSISDN is stored in a file in the SIMCard." so my question is, is this number spoofable/modifiable by a malicious user?

Comment: In order to write that field in the simcard, you must have the PIN code. Only with that code you will receive write permission..

Answer (score 1):

another way of going through it is to make the user input their number. 
then send an SMS to this number entered.

validate that this message has been received, then u can categorically say that the user has entered the correct MSISDN and you store this.

simples :)