# Cant get phoneNumber ionic cordova

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, ionic3, phone-number

I have simple code

```
import { Sim } from '@ionic-native/sim';
    constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private sim: Sim, public navCtrl: NavController, private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) {
this.sim.requestReadPermission().then(
          () => console.log('Permission granted'),
          () => console.log('Permission denied')
      );
  public goToReport(){
            this.sim.getSimInfo().then((info) => console.log(info.phoneNumber))
    }
```

but i get empty string. When i try to console something like `console.log(info.deviceId)` /Its need READ_PHONE_STATE permissions as phone number too everything work fine

Comment: Have you tried by wrapping the code in the constructor inside of the platform ready, like this: `this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
      // ...
    });`?

Comment: I try do this `this.plt.ready().then((readySource) =>this.sim.getSimInfo().then((info) => console.log(info.phoneNumber)))` but itstill not working

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the docs, especially the [return-object docs](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim#return-object) you will find a footnote there:

> Notice: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone/6797278#6797278), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922734/getting-reliable-msisdn-from-android-phone-voicemailnumber-line1number), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861064/retrieving-line1-number-from-telephonymanager-in-android) article). Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string.