# how to get SIM Information in ionic cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I am using cordova plugin cordova-plugin-sim2 for get sim data.It's working fine with dual sim device but when trying to used with single sim device it's showing all data except mobile number.It's showing empty string "" not return mobile number.

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://github.com/scwl/cordova-plugin-sim#android-quirks) mention:

> Notice: the content of phoneNumber is unreliable (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922734/getting-reliable-msisdn-from-android-phone-voicemailnumber-line1number) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861064/retrieving-line1-number-from-telephonymanager-in-android) article).

Getting the phone-number (MSISDN) is not very reliable. The original [sim plugin docs](https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim#return-object) (the one this one was forked from) mention that that phone number will be an empty string in case it could not be determined:

> Sometimes phoneNumber is only an empty string.